# Docker compose in asp.net core offline (no internet connexion) : unable to load the service index for source

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, offline

I am using an offline machine of a company (without internet connexion). When I do docker-compose, I have the error : Unable to load service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. (Which is normal because I have no internet on my machine). The problem is, even though I changed the Nuget.config file (so the path "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" is no longer in Nuget.config), I still have the same error:

[Error: Unable to load service index for source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrozo.png)

Here you have the docker file of my service :
[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdkOV.png)

And the docker-compose:
[docker-compose file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RZDG.png)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the `dotnet restore` in the Dockerfile, you've only copied the .csproj file into the container.

Copy the nuget.config file into the container as well, before doing `dotnet restore`.